# Media Foundation encode AVI Raw index error

Tags: c++, directshow, video-encoding, avi, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to encode a video using MediaFoundation on Windows 8.1, the output file should be an avi container, with a raw stream NV12.
The video is generated, and I can play it but when I open it with VLC I get the broken index detected (With options to play as is or fix it temporarly). If I press play as is, it plays ok. But this is generating a problem in other softwares.
I tried to research this and noticed that AVI supports 2 types of indexing

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318189(v=vs.85).aspx

But this is for DirectShow and I am using MediaFoundation and I can't find anything related to this inside MediaFoundation.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Edit:
This is how I am creating the IMFMediaSink:

```
hr = MFCreateAttributes(&sinkAttributes, 5);
assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
sinkAttributes->SetUnknown(MF_SINK_WRITER_ASYNC_CALLBACK, this);
sinkAttributes->SetGUID(MF_TRANSCODE_CONTAINERTYPE, MFTranscodeContainerType_AVI);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)){
    hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(videoURL, NULL, sinkAttributes, (IMFSinkWriter**)&sinkWriter);
}
```

Comment: Do you use the MFCreateAVIMediaSink? Have you also tried to create a transcoding topolgy?

Comment: No, I am using IMFMediaSink and creating it with a URL. I am not converting, I am generating a new video. When creating the IMFMediaSink I tell it it's an AVI container.

Comment: How exactly do you createthe imfmediasink?

Comment: I added the code to the question. Forgive me I meant IMFSinkWriter instead of IMFMediaSink in the previous comment.

Comment: Are you sure that the final file is actuallyan avi. On windows 8 the MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL maybe creates an AVI sink.

Comment: Yes it is an AVI file, I even checked it with HxEdit, also if I run an ffmpeg copy command only, the resulting avi will work well anywhere, it's just a problem with indexing. I am setting the timestamp and duration of each sample, plus I tried telling the encoder that each frame is a key frame (since it's raw). But none made any effect.

Comment: Windows 8.1 and 10. I know Container AVI is only available starting windows 8.1 (It doesn't even generate a video on windows 8)

Comment: I think that the problem is due to incorrect timestamps and/or FPS configured in the media type you use in AddStream/SetInputType.

Comment: That is not the case, because:
1-The video plays normally.
2-I am creating other video formats and they are working well.
3-I tried to hardcore the FPS, or just receive and send the values from another video =>same behavior.